# Скрипт .bat | Изменение кодировки

Tags: windows, кодировка, cmd, bat

Как поменять кодировку во всех файлах указанной директории, затем сохранить их.
любые способы приветствуются.

Comment: Можно взять утилиту [iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm),  вызвать ее в цикле для каждого файла.

Comment: `notepad++` умеет, если не хочешь скриптов.